# Why is a transaction full rollback?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

The innerInvoke method is called in the outerInvoke method, and `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` is used in the innerInvoke method to prevent any problem in the transaction applied to the outerInvoke method even if there is a problem in the transaction applied to the innerInvoke method.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OuterService {

    private final InnerService innerService;
    private final FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void outerInvoke() {
        fooRepository.save(new Foo("foo"));
        innerService.innerInvoke();
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InnerService {

    private final BarRepository barRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void innerInvoke() {
        try {
            barRepository.save(new Bar("bar"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("innerInvoke Exception : {}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
class TransactionPropagationTestApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private OuterService outerService;

    @Test
    @Rollback(value = false)
    void saveTest() {
        outerService.outerInvoke();
    }

}
```

However, if an IdentifierGenerationException, a subtype of DataAccessException, occurs in outerInvoke, all transactions are rolled back.

In my opinion, since the transactions are separated, the transaction of the outerInvoke method should be committed and the transaction of the innerInvoke method should be rolled back, so why are they all rolled back?

Comment: Because your try/catch is breaking proper transaction management. Leading to a commit on the inner transaction, which leads to an exception, which will rollback the outer transaction and thus everything.

Comment: @M.Deinum
If the exception is handled in outerInvoke rather than innerInvoke, outerInvoke has been successfully committed. Can you explain more why the full rollback occurs when handling the exception in innerInvoke?

Comment: The rollback occurs if the exception is seen by the transaction management stuff, when you are catching it yourself inside the method, the transaction management doesn't see the exception and thus will do a commit.

Comment: @M.Deinum 
Thank you for answer. However, since the transaction of outerInvoke() and the transaction of innerInvoke() are completely separated through Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, shouldn't outerInvoke() be committed normally even if there is a problem after the innerInvoke() transaction is committed?

What you said makes sense when it's Propagation.REQUIRE, but it doesn't make sense when it's a completely different transaction via Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: The `REQUIRES_NEW` should be rolled back, it isn't because of you catching the exception.Why it rollsback in your case, is because it **thinks** it can commit, it cannot and will throw another exception (which tells you it cannot commit due to a transaction marked rollback only), which is then been seen by the outer transaction which in turn will rollback as well (because it sees an exception). I suspect it will throw an `UnexpectedRollbackException` with that message.

Comment: @M.Deinum
Thank you for answer. Could you please explain in more detail? I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: What part is it you don't understand? An exception is catched, commit occurs falsely, throws an exception, outer transaction rollsback... Not sure what there is more to explain.

Comment: @M.Deinum 

Oh, an exception is raised in innerInvoke(), but an exception is handled and a commit occurs, and an exception is raised because the commit fails, is it correct that the exception affects the external transaction as well?

Comment: It affects **only** the outer transaction as that is what sees the exception.

Comment: @M.Deinum
I thought that the exception that occurred when an invalid commit occurred would also be caught by the exception handling of the InnerService.innerInvoke() method, so I thought that there would be no problem with the external transaction.

Comment: No it should see the original exception **but** due to you catching that, the exception handling itself will throw an exception, the `UnexpectedRollbackException` as mentioned earlier.